# making list of function output affecting elements from input args indexes

Tags: python, function, matrix, arguments

```
def task(func, *seq):
"""
The function receives a function and N sequences (lists/tuples).
All sequences have the same length M.
The number of arguments of the func is equal to the number of sequences.
Return a list of [res1, res2, ..., resM], where:

res1 = func(seq1[1], seq2[1], ..., seqN[1])
res2 = func(seq1[2], seq2[2], ..., seqN[2])
...
resM = func(seq1[M], seq2[M], ..., seqN[M])
"""
# BEGIN
  result = [] 
  transpose = list(zip(*seq))
  for i in transpose:
    result.append(func([i]))
  return result
```

For example, following this logic:

```
lamt = [6, 5, 1, 55, 1, 14], [8, 22, 2, 7, 12, 3], [6, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5]
trans = list(zip(*lamt))
[(lambda x, y, z: x*y-z)(x,y,z) for (x,y,z) in trans]
```

works fine. but can't reproduce in code.

Could you please tell me, whats wrong with, or how to do it better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use the builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) in connjunction with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to do this for you:

```
def task(func, *seq):
    return map(func, zip(*seq))
```

A single run of this function would work like the following, where we sum the first elements togather, the second elements togather, and the third elements togather:

```
>>> def task(func, *seq):
...     return map(func, zip(*seq))
... 
>>> lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
>>> task(sum, *lists)
[22, 26, 30]
```

---

As for your original code, it doesn't work because you convert the tuple you get into a list of tuple when you do `result.append(func([i]))` instead of `result.append(func(i))`

So instead do:

```
>>> def task(func, *seq):
...   result = [] 
...   transpose = list(zip(*seq))
...   for i in transpose:
...     result.append(func(i))
...   return result
... 
>>> task(sum, *lists)
[22, 26, 30]
```

---

If you do want to apply custom lambdas, you can unpack the arguments explicitly using:

```
>>> def task(func, *seq):
...   result = [] 
...   transpose = list(zip(*seq))
...   for i in transpose:
...     result.append(func(*list(i)))
...   return result
... 
>>> task(lambda x, y, z, a: x*y + z*a, *lists)
[74, 98, 126]
```

Note that you will have to be very careful about the number of inputs the lambda takes, else the unpacking may not happen correctly and will throw an error.

Comment: Ye, thanks for telling about 'map', but still can't pass test. `def test_ok():
    assert task(lambda x: x * 2, [1, 2, 3]) == [2, 4, 6]` returns `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)] != [2, 4, 6]`

Comment: @kAldown You are mixing the inputs, `[1, 2, 3]` is a single list, and not a list of lists. This won't work for sure.

Comment: but it doesn't work even with `lam = lambda x, y, z: x * y - z
    assert task(lam, [6, 5, 1], [8, 22, 2], [6, 1, 1]) == [42, 109, 1]`

Comment: @kAldown That works for me, In fact the opposite `assert task(lam, [6, 5, 1], [8, 22, 2], [6, 1, 1]) != [42, 109, 1]` throws the `AssertionError `.

Comment: I also thought so, because even implementin condition to catch when `len(seq) == 1` and passing through every element by `[i for j in zip(*seq) for i in j]` won't work either. Sad thing that I'm only one who can't pass exam, and I can't reach teacher =(. Still thanks for such work, very appriciate, will mark as done, if things will clearify.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Doesn't mentioned your last edit about passing `*list(i)`. Wonder, why lambda can't get tuple of 3 elements, why it needs lists of 3 elements?

Comment: @kAldown That's because previously there wass no unpacking involved, so the lambda would take the list as a single argument.